# two weaker servers or one more powerful?

Tags: linux

I have several scripts in the node, each script running in a separate container.
Which option is best, one powerful server or two weaker servers instead powerful one?

**Spec powerful server:**

Intel Xeon E3-1270v6

4c / 8t

3.8GHz

64GB DDR4 ECC 2400MHz

SoftRaid 2x450GB NVME

**Spec weaker servers:**
Intel Xeon D1520

4c / 8t

2.2GHz

32GB DDR3 ECC 2133MHz

SoftRaid 2x480GB SSD

Comment: it depend but powerful is always good(mostly), it depend on what kind of workload you want to run and how resource matter for execution. Kindly add more details such as what kind of workload you want to run cpu,memory,io etc requirements.

Comment: Did you see: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) I am sorry but Capaticity-Planning is not on topic for Serverfault. Having more ram might in generally a better solution.